# Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Dr Stone anime end in?

Tags: dr.stone

Which chapter of the manga does Season 2 of Dr Stone anime end in?

since it only ended yesterday i coulden't find an answer anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dr. Stone season 2 ends at chapter 83 of the manga. so you should start reading from chapter 84 onwards